# How events are more robust than delegates

Tags: c#, .net

Consider the following example.

The `Stock` class fires its `PriceChanged` event every
time the Price of the Stock changes:

```
public delegate void PriceChangedHandler (decimal oldPrice,decimal newPrice);
public class Stock
{
    string symbol;
    decimal price;
    public Stock (string symbol) { this.symbol = symbol; }
    public event PriceChangedHandler PriceChanged;
    public decimal Price
    {
        get { return price; }
        set
        {
            if (price == value) return; // Exit if nothing has changed
            if (PriceChanged != null) // If invocation list not empty,
            PriceChanged (price, value); // fire event.
            price = value;
        }
    }
}
```

If we remove the event keyword from our example so that `PriceChanged` becomes an
ordinary delegate field, our example would give the same results. However, `Stock`
would be less robust,

My question is in what way the event keyword makes the stock more robust?

Answer (score 4):

> My question is in what way the event keyword makes the stock more robust?

It's all a matter of what clients outside the class can do. If this were just a public field, then anyone could:

- Call all existing handlers themselves
- Remove/replace all existing handlers

Instead, by using an event, other code can *only* subscribe to the event or unsubscribe from it. I wouldn't use the word "robust" to describe this difference - it's a matter of encapsulation, and expressing what other code should be able to do with an instance of `Stock`.

See my [article on delegates and events](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx) for more information.

Comment: In addition it changes the One-to-Many / One-to-One meaning. if its only delegate, it can be set only to one function at a time, while event can "fire" many functions

Comment: @ilansch: No, that's not true. Delegates are multicast. So you could use `stock.PriceChanged = firstHandler + secondHandler;`

Comment: i don't see how a subscriber could call all existing handlers himself. Could you give an instance showing that?

Comment: @GauravAhuja: By reading the field! They'd just call `stock.PriceChanged(10m, 20m)`

Comment: Hi John, for a subscriber to call all existing handlers himself, he will need an existing instance of the delegate (i.e. an object of the Stock class). I think every subscriber will have his own instance of the delegate and it won't matter whether we use event or not?

Comment: Please let me know an instance how will each subscriber share a same instance of the delegate? I mean I will be providing a DLL of the publisher class to subscribers so that they can use it. How will using the event keyword benefit me as publisher?

Comment: @GauravAhuja: You're getting confused between an instance of the `Stock` class and the delegate instance. They're not the same thing. The point is that *in general* there may be multiple "consumers" of the same `Stock` object, each wishing to add/remove handlers... they shouldn't be able to interfere with each other or call each other's handlers. This *may* not be a concern in your specific case, but I would still stick with the event approach rather than just allowing direct access to the handlers field.